# Using Loop multiple times

Tags: loops, autohotkey

### 1. Briefly

I don't understand, how I can use cycles from `Loop` multiple times without ending script.

---

### 2. Settings

I have a file `SashaAutoScrolling.ahk`, it content:

```autohotkey
; First loop, Speed 1
#+1::
Loop
{
    Send {WheelDown}
    Sleep 3000
}

; Second loop, Speed 2
#+2::
Loop
{
    Send {WheelDown}
    Sleep 600
}

; Third loop, Speed 3
#+3::
Loop
{
    Send {WheelDown}
    Sleep 100
}

; Fourth loop, Speed Up
#+0::
Loop
{
    Send {WheelUp}
    Sleep 600
}

; Loop pause
; http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/95308-endless-loop-with-hotkey-pause/?p=600526
#p::Pause

; Exit script
#esc::ExitApp
```

---

### 3. Steps to reproduce

I open any `pdf` file in any PDF-viewer. I switch between «speeds»:

- <kbd>Shift+Super+3</kbd>,
- <kbd>Shift+Super+0</kbd>,
- <kbd>Shift+Super+2</kbd>,
- <kbd>Shift+Super+3</kbd>,
- <kbd>Shift+Super+0</kbd>.

---

### 4. Actual behavior

[image: Actual]

**If** I run <kbd>Shift+Super+3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Super+0</kbd> first time

I can successful switch between «speeds».

**If** I run <kbd>Shift+Super+3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Super+0</kbd> second and next times,

I can't switch between «speeds».

---

### 5. Expected behavior

Successful switch between «speeds» unlimited number of times.

---

### 6. Not helped

1. Googling, searching in Stack Overflow and AutoHotkey forum.

---

### 7. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer use third-party programs. Adobe Reader free version [**works as expected**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpfp4-kinn4), but I can't read, use this program , for example, `djvu` or `doc` books.
2. Please, do not offer use [**built-in mouse auto scrolling**](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001495.htm). It uncomfortable, because is problematic quick choose exact comfortable «speed» for reading.

Comment: The reason your script only works once is probably because when you press ESC, `ExitApp` exits AutoHotKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code scrolls current window with simulated mouse wheel scrolls**

<kbd>Shift+Win+1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+Win+2</kbd>, etc... starts scrolling. If already scrolling, just updates sleep interval. <kbd>esc</kbd> exits

```
; globals:
;   g_running : true while loop is active
;   g_sleep   : milliseconds to sleep between sending input event
;   g_key     : key to simulate


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; HOTKEY DEFINITIONS

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

#+1:: scrollit(3000)
#+2:: scrollit(600)
#+3:: scrollit(300)
#+0:: scrollit(600,"WheelUp")

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 1

Esc:: abort()


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; HELPER FUNCTIONS

; send wheeldown every _delay_ microseconds
; if called while loop is already active, just update delay and exit
;
scrollit(sleep, key="WheelDown")
{
  global g_running
  global g_sleep := sleep
  global g_key   := key

  if g_running
    return

  g_running := true

  while (g_running)
  {
    Send {%g_key%}
    Sleep g_sleep
  }
}



abort()
{
  global g_running := false
}
```

Comment: But if user wants `{WheelUp}`, he still need press to `Esc`. Thanks.

Comment: okay, I parameterized the input event instead of assuming WheelDown all the time (which is now just a default)

Comment: Can't decide if I should upvote your answer for the creative and working solution or downvote because it will block the UI thread(or event loop) in any other language(maybe not all but definitely most). It's probably fine for autohotkey but people who will see it probably won't understand why it works and might get some wrong ideas about how a problem like this one should be solved(with a timer). If you see things differently please tell me.

Comment: I don't see my answer as creative or unique.  It's structured similarly to the [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) used by every windows program with a graphical interface.  The `sleep` statement yields control just as `GetMessage()` does.  Feel free to post your "right" way as an alternate solution.

Comment: It's not, your code is structured similarly to calling `sleep` after `GetMessage()` and freezing. `sleep` doesn't yield control of the current thread, that statement doesn't even make any sense. Your code works only because of the unique threading model of autohotkey. I posted an alternative solution.

Comment: I meant `sleep` yields control of the cpu allowing for any other related processing to complete. I did not mean to imply anything about how threads are processed. Script authors shouldn't assume that autohotkey and the scripts it launches are all a single thread. When I program in autohotkey, I think of launching a hotkey as similar to launching a shell script; the script can use any reasonable program structure without worrying about blocking operating system threads.

Answer (score 1):

**Scrolls current window by simulating mouse wheel scroll when <kbd>Shift+Win+1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+Win+2</kbd>, etc. pressed.  <kbd>esc</kbd> exits loop**

```
#+1:: scrollit(3000)
#+2:: scrollit(600)
#+3:: scrollit(300)
Esc:: abort()

scrollit(delay)
{
  global abort := false
  while (!abort)
  {
    Send {WheelDown}
    Sleep delay
  }
}


abort()
{
  global abort := true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible switch between «speeds» without pressing `Esc` each time, [**as in Adobe Reader**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpfp4-kinn4)?

Comment: I added another answer that makes scrollit reentrant

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because by default there is only one thread per hotkey. When you do:

```
Loop
{
    Send {WheelDown}
    Sleep 100
}
```

You never return from this one thread so when you call it second time the hotkey will not fire and your program will continue looping in the current thread.

[Jim U](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45593722/1398418) solved it by calling `#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2`, this wouldn't have made your code work though because you don't return from your hotkey threads at all, Jim U doesn't return from the first thread only so 2 threads is enough for his solutoin to work.

An alternative solution is to use timers, the following will change the scrolling speed immediately, doesn't need any special directives and doesn't rely on Autohotkeys unique threading model.

```
#+1::callSetTimer(3000)
#+2::callSetTimer(600)
#+3::callSetTimer(100)
#+0::callSetTimer(600, "WheelUp")
Esc::SetTimer, scrollTimer, Off

callSetTimer(interval, key := "WheelDown") {
    global currKey := key
    SetTimer, scrollTimer, %interval%

    scrollTimer:
        send, {%currKey%}
    return
}
```